# list_of Posts in WPGraphQL

Tags: wordpress, graphql, gatsby, wordpress-gutenberg, wp-graphql

I'm creating a new Gutenberg ACF Block. I want to be able to dynamically provide a list of Post objects in GraphQL for Gatsby to read.

Here is my code which works in WordPress GraphiQL and in Gatsby's GraphQL to return a single Post.

Gutenberg Block Code:
[image]

Gatsby GraphQL:
[image]

But if I change it to return a list of Posts, this does work in WordPress GraphiQL but returns an empty list in Gatsby's GraphQL.

Gutenberg Block Code:

[image]

WordPress GraphiQL:

[image]

Gatsby GraphQL:

[image]

I'm using gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental 1.3.8 for Gatsby.

Am I wrapping the list of Post objects wrong? Has someone else ever provided a list of Post types in WP GraphQL before?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can solve this problem:

- Review this: [Custom field not saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63582514/custom-field-not-saved)
- Watch this video: https://youtu.be/Po9gyc51HlQ?t=3488
- Include this code in PHP: May sure you set the fromType as the originating object, and the toType as to the object that you need to connect to in list_of

[image]

Happy coding!